# What favor did Chenault done to Paul?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, the-rum-diary

In *The Rum Diary (2011)*, Paul providing shelter to Chenault who left his
boyfriend Sanderson. Paul came to Chenault who is sleeping on his bed.

> Cheanult: I stole your bed.
>
> Paul: It's okay. I'm going to write.
>
> Cheanult: I'm so sorry.
>
> Paul: Don't be sorry. **You did me the best favor I ever had**.

What favor did Chenault done to Paul before?